Making a Quickbooks online app in Java/Nodejs to send updates to a webhook
I am making an app in quickbooks online that will listen for any updates in items and send that to a webhook, preferrably zapier's webhook. However, I cannot get the app working.
At first, I cloned the repo mentioned in their docs titled SampleApp-WebhookNotifications-nodejs. Then I copy pasted the required keys like clientId, clientSecret, redirectUri, webhookUri, webhooksVerifier in the config.json and hit npm install -> npm start.
When I went ahead and tested it by updating an item in my qbo and seeing if I get any response in Zapier, but I got nothing.
After much struggle, I found out that I may need to execute the authorization flow, which wasn't inherently there in the webhooknotification nodejs repo. I found their repo titled oauth-nodejs, which basically lets me connect using email and password. But that does not have the webhook functionality.
So basically, one sample app has webhooks functionality, but doesn't work probably because of the oauth flow. Another sample app only has the oauth flow, but no webhook functionality.
I tried to combine the two, but just couldn't wrap my head around what was going on. This is the same with Java apps as well.
Am I on the right track in idenfiying the problem? Or am I completely off? In any case, I need your valuable insights on this. Thanks.
